# wget not saving images while --page-requisites is on

Tags: wget

I try to save images from a site using wget. I have `--page-requisites` in the command line but it doesn't save the images. For the rest everything goes so fine, it even saves the extension.

```
  wget \
     --recursive \
     --no-clobber \
     --page-requisites \
     --html-extension \
     --convert-links \
     --restrict-file-names=windows \
         http://leveldesigninspirationmachine.tumblr.com/
```

Why doesn't it get the images?